# Django with watchtower region error when deploying to Elastic-Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to use watchtower with my Django API when deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I have just about run out of Google pages. When I deploy using AWS EB CLI I get an error stating that:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'watchtower': You must specify a region.
```

I have tried adding my credentials in multiple ways to try to solve this. I have put them in the settings.py file, the credentials file in the .aws dir (both csv and no extension).

Settings.py:

```py
import os
from datetime import timedelta
from boto3.session import Session
from boto3 import client

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MY-KEy'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Shhh Secret Key'
AWS_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'

boto3_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                        region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME)
```

as I stated I also have a dir named ".aws" in my root dir with the credentials:

```
[default]
region = us-east-2
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = key
```

My config files:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
      option_name: WSGIPath
      value: Wesbite/wsgi.py
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      value: Wesbite.settings
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
      option_name: StreamLogs
      value: true
```

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  03_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: Wesbite.settings
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "my_eb_site/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"
```

Here is a full output of the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'watchtower': You must specify a region.
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/db-migrate.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-09-08 01:17:39    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

Thanks for any insights!

Edit:
In cloudwatch the error also states:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Comment: I added AWS_DEFAULT_REGION as an environment variable in the container, and that solved the problem.  I couldn't find any obvious way to specify the region when setting up the log handler.    (In my case I added this env file to the AWS::Batch::JobDefinition.ContainerProperties.Environment section of my serverless yaml.)